# How do you send input to a jar through process builder while also receiving output from the jar as well

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm trying to use process builder to run a shell. The shell runs a jar that I need to read input from, but the only way I found to continuously receive updates from the shell was to use a while loop.

My problem is that with the while loop, it seems there isn't a way to passively throw commands to the shell for my jar to execute without halting my update.

How would I get input from my jar while also being able to tell it what to do?

```
public void init(String dir, String file) throws IOException 
{
    serverDir = dir;
    jar = getJar(file);

    builder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash");
    proc = builder.start();

    osw = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream());
    bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

    s = new Scanner(proc.getInputStream());  
    input = new Scanner(System.in);

    init = true;
    print("Successfully Initiated");
}

public void startServer(String dir, String file) throws Exception
{
    if(!init) 
    {       
        init(dir, file);
        run("cd " + serverDir + "&& java -Xmx1024M -jar " + jar + " -o true");
        print("Server Started");

        while (s.hasNext()) 
        {
            if(input.hasNext())
                run("help");

            print(s.nextLine());

        }
        s.close();
    } else 
        print("Server Start Failed, Initiate First!");
}

public void run(String cmd) throws Exception
{
    bw.write(cmd);
    bw.newLine();
    bw.flush();

    print("Successfully Ran: " + s);
}
```

Comment: You have to use threads.

Comment: @Andreas how would I go about using threads in this situation?

Comment: You create a thread for reading the command output (using `getInputStream()`, and `getErrorStream()` if you didn't call `redirectErrorStream(true)`), and write command inputs (using `getOutputStream()`) in the main thread.